# How do I restore shutdown button?

Tags: shutdown

I have ubuntu 15.10.
the button in the top right hand corner of the screen is missing. I have to use ctrl alt del to shut down or restart or suspend Ubuntu. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

Please try running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-session

sudo apt-get install indicator-session
```

Then restart you machine.

Comment: I tried this, but no change. I did notice that in the login window the power button is there, but when I login there is no power button.

Comment: I also had installed an app called ClassicMenu Indicator. When your instructions did not work. I thought maybe uninstalling it would work. It did not. So I tried your instructions again and still no joy.

Comment: did you install anything else, say Cairo docks perhaps?

Comment: Nothing that I would think would affect that. Just an arcade game maybe a card game. A Bible program. Can't think of anything else.